# Bash: changing font size

Tags: bash, fonts

This will change the font to yellow:

```
echo -e "\E[1;33m"
```

How exactly can I make it bold and increase the font size, whilst keeping the yellowness?

Comment: font size is not dependent upon bash but it is dependent upon the terminal

Comment: You can use ANSI escapes (or `tput`) for bold just like for color: http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/terminalcodes. Either way, don't forget to reset the output when you're done.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on a console you can try changing the consoles resolution with [vidcontrol](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=vidcontrol&sektion=1) (for BSD) or playing with the framebuffer settings (for GNU/Linux).

If you are using X then use control - middle mouse button to click on the window and select another size. (Usually you will get a list with tiny/small/medium/large/huge as a choice).